# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu GNOME, GRUB not loading

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gnome, uefi, windows-10

So basically I've installed Ubuntu GNOME alongside an existing Windows 10 install, and I can't boot into Ubuntu at all. I can't access the UEFI boot menu through Windows Advanced Restart (which is something I used to be able to do, did Windows patch this out?...).

I tried running this command which I found on various sites saying that it will make the GRUB bootloader load first:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

But now my computer just boots to a blank screen for a minute or so before finally loading Windows 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you recently update Windows to the Anniversary Update? That update borked Grub and you may need to repair/reinstall it.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here.  Also, please tell us what make/model computer (or motherboard) you're using. Some manufacturers are known to deliver broken EFIs.

Comment: I've made some progress, but I still have issues. Please see this post for an update: http://askubuntu.com/questions/841941/cant-boot-into-windows-10-through-grub

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

I had the same problem while dual-booting. In my case, i had lost the grub totally.

so make make a bootable ubuntu pen-Drive and boot into it.
go in live mode. and follow the instructions [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

It worked fine for me. (wanted to comment this but too low rep.)