# Can't boot into Windows 10 through GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gnome, bootloader, windows-10

I installed GNOME on my Windows 10 PC so that I can dual boot them. Originally I couldn't boot to GRUB at all, it would just boot to Windows. I also noticed I can't access UEFI firmware through Advanced Restart (yes, I have checked and my computer is UEFI). So I cannot disable secure boot or alter the boot order. I did some searching, and I found this command on another AskUbuntu post, so I ran it:

```
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} "path\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"` in command prompt.
```

The computer now successfully boots to `GRUB` and I can load Ubuntu. However, I get an error: `cannot load image` whenever I choose a Windows Boot Loader option. I've also read that disabling secure boot will fix this, but I don't now how to boot to UEFI. Any suggestions as to how I can boot back into Windows without having to reinstall it over the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`

Documentation: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--firmware-setup

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm away for the weekend but I'll try that out as soon as I can. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I get the error "cannot indicate to EFI to boot into setup mode: No such file or directory"